# Windows10 dynamic virtual folders controlled via an program

Tags: windows-10, smb, folder-redirection, mapped-drive

Hi is it possible to dynamically redirect an folder for example
E:\1\2\3 to run (a.exe -dir E:\1\2\3) witch will then redirect to C:/Data/Example
if not I think it shound be possible by running an smb shere I dont mind what lang gets used relay but maybe python or C# would be good

Comment: There may be a more efficient way of doing it, but one solution is to use `system("mklink ...")`, or its equivalent in the language of your choice.

Comment: How can i use that dynamically if i goto E:/blah/blah how do i get the program to deside where it redirs to

Comment: I have no idea what criteria are used to make this redirection decision. Only you know that.

Comment: Why do you need to know why i made this decision

Comment: I don't understand your question. You build the `mklink` string with the options and parameters you want, including the target directory. I represented that by `mklink ...`, but it's up to you to create the full parameter list.

Comment: So if I using Windows explorer goto C:\Example that needs to run code to dynamically redirect it to where ever the code desides may be different ever time not just an simple mklink

Comment: I'm afraid the question is still not clear. Are you trying to make a specific program use a folder other than the one it does by default? Do you understand what symbolic links are? Why do they not satisfy your use case?